# how to enable vertical scrollbar of an edittext programmatically

Tags: android, scrollbar, android-edittext

I'm trying to implement `android:scrollbars="vertical"` in XML by Java code.
I've tried method `setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true)` but it doesn't work.
Anyone can give me a suggestion?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you can use
    `EditText ed=new EditText(context);
     ed.setScroller(new Scroller(context));
     ed.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);`

this will give the scroll option for the edit text but it won't show the scroll bar.